# c# perform commands immediately

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void test()
 {
 for(int i=1; int i<5; i++)
  { 
     if(i==1)       
     button1.BackColor=Color.White;
     if(i==2) 
     button2.BackColor=Color.White;
     if(i==3)   
     button3.BackColor=Color.White;
     if(i==4) 
     button4.BackColor=Color.White;
     Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
```

Now, the program waits 400 ms and then all 4 buttons change color simultaneously. I want it to wait 100ms each time and change the color of a button each 100ms, so I can see a clear sequence of first button1 changing, then button2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Application.DoEvents()` after each change.  Your function is occupying the thread so that the UI won't be updated until it exits.

See [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public void test()
 {
 for(int i=1; int i<5; i++)
  { 
     if(i==1)       
     button1.BackColor=Color.White;
     if(i==2) 
     button2.BackColor=Color.White;
     if(i==3)   
     button3.BackColor=Color.White;
     if(i==4) 
     button4.BackColor=Color.White;

     Application.DoEvents();
     Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep(100)` prevent UI thread from drawing, but you can force button refresh and change back color on each iteration with `Refresh` method:

```
public void test()
{    
        Button[] buttons = new Button[] { button1, button2, button3, button4, };
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].BackColor = Color.White;                
            buttons[i].Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }    
}
```